# Ayuda - no puedo enviar objeto de la vista hacia el controlador llegan atributos nulos

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

tengo un problema

Intento enviar un objeto en javascript a mi controlador, el problema es que el controlador recibe como un atributo de lista y esta lista contiene otra lista como un atributo.

Creo que el problema es que no envío o no creo bien mi objeto javascript.

alguien podría ayudarme a decirme si mi error es crear el objeto incorrectamente o si está en otra parte

Este es el objeto que hice.

```
   var retrabajoPiezas = {
      claveSubMenu: "",
      claveContenedorOrigen: "",
      claveContenedorDestino: "",
      Lotes: [{ Defectos: [{ Clave: "", DefectoId: 0, Nombre: "" }] }],
      UsuarioId: 1,
   };
```

Envio en este Ajax el objeto.

```
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "http://localhost/api/Contenedores/RetrabajoPiezas",
        dataType: "json",
        data: retrabajoPiezas,
        traditional: true,
        success: function (datos) {

        },
        error: function () {
            ErrorBottom("JS: Error de servidor al mover piezas.");
        }
    });
```

Esto recive el metodo en C#

```
  public HttpResponseMessage RetrabajoPiezas(RetrabajoPiezas retrabajoPiezas) 
  {
     ObjectParameter outputMensaje = VariablesEstaticas.outputmensajeError; 
   }
```

Esta es la clase del objeto que recibo en mi metodo

```
  public class RetrabajoPiezas
  {
    public string ClaveSubMenu { get; set; }
    public string ClaveContenedorOrigen { get; set; }
    public string ClaveContenedorDestino { get; set; }
    public List<LotesClasificacionMaquinadoPiezasDTO> Lotes { get; set; }
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }
  }
```

esta es la segunda clase (la lista que se encuentra en la clase anterior)

```
  public class LotesClasificacionMaquinadoPiezasDTO : LotesDefectosDTO
 {
    public LotesClasificacionMaquinadoPiezasDTO()
    {
       Defectos = new List<ReporteDefectoDTO>();
    }
    public List<ReporteDefectoDTO> Defectos { get; set; }
  }
```

y aqui esta la clase que contiene la lista anterior

```
 public class  ReporteDefectoDTO
{
   public int DefectoId { get; set; }
   public string Clave { get; set; }
   public string Nombre { get; set; }
 }
```

como ven si me llega un Lote pero la lista de Defectos no
[image: Adjunto esta imagen]

[image: console.log del objeto]

este es un console.log del objeto que envio en ajax

Comment: Podrias hacer un console.log del objeto que envias? a simple vista no veo nada malo.. salvo que algun nombre este fallando y por eso no pueda parsear el objeto que llega

Comment: hola @gbianchi, claro dejame editar el post para subir una imagen del console.log

Comment: a mi surge la duda de el array de  objetos que tienes dentro del objeto, los ma probable  es que tengas que tratarlo de una sola manera, ademas no tienes una coma cuando terminas el array

Comment: hola @SebastiánLagosYañez ¿te refieres a crear esos arreglos fuera del objeto?

Comment: si lo puedes hacer así no hay problema , pero revisa la parte de lotes , te falta la coma al final

Comment: mira esto @JehTron https://js.do/code/253360, quiza te sirva. Inspecciona el sitio y mira la consola, así se crea un objeto dentro de otro

Comment: Gracias @SebastiánLagosYañez intente eso aunque sigo sin recibir el Defecto

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar pasando los datos como Json y agregando el content-type:

```
var retrabajoPiezasJson = JSON.stringify(retrabajoPiezas);

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "http://localhost/api/Contenedores/RetrabajoPiezas",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: retrabajoPiezasJson,
        traditional: true,
        success: function (datos) {

        },
        error: function () {
            ErrorBottom("JS: Error de servidor al mover piezas.");
        }
    });
```

Saludos!